# Generate XML root with capital letter?

Tags: ruby, xml

I'm using the [xml/mapping](http://xml-mapping.rubyforge.org/) library, and here's how I generate XML:

```
xml = user.save_to_xml
str = String.new
xml.write(str,2)
```

The result is a little different from what I want. It generates the XML tags with a lower-case letter:

```
<user PK=...
 ...
</user>
```

But I need the tag to start with a capital letter:

```
<User PK=...
 ...
</User>
```

How do I force the generation with an upper-case letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the default `root_element_name` like so:

```
User.root_element_name "User"
```

If you want to modify the default for all classes, you'll need to override the `default_root_element_name` method which is defined as:

```
# The default root element name for this class. Equals the class
# name, with all parent module names stripped, and with capital
# letters converted to lowercase and preceded by a dash;
# e.g. "Foo::Bar::MySampleClass" becomes "my-sample-class".
def default_root_element_name
  self.name.split('::')[-1].gsub(/^(.)/){$1.downcase}.gsub(/(.)([A-Z])/){$1+"-"+$2.downcase}
end
```